# Uploading Login Form

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have created a login form using **xampp** on my computer. I am quite new to php and was wondering how I would go about uploading this to my website. As when I've tried it just says cant connect.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any app to connect ?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the files via ftp protocol to your webspace/Server. Try filezila